# Inequality $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{3n+1}>1$

Tags: inequality, summation, fractions, arithmetic-progressions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Show that $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{3n+1}>1,\:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
This is a 9th grade problem.
I was trying to take the greatest numerator, which is the  last numerator of the last fraction. But there are only $2n+1$ terms. Right?
After that I have no idea. Thx!

Comment: Maybe by induction?

Comment: I haven't checked whether it works, but I would try "pairing up" the terms. Starting from both ends: 1st + last, 2nd+the penultimate et cetera. You get a lower bound $n(a_n+a_{n+2})+a_{n+1}$ which may be just enough.

Comment: Gimusi is right, induction may be easier. I do have some doubts whether 9th graders are expected to be familiar with induction ANYWHERE (on this planet) :-)

Comment: A.M-G.M. and pairing up first and last, maybe?  $\frac {1}{n+k+1} + \frac {1}{3n - k + 1} \ge 2\sqrt{\frac 1{(n-k + 1)(3n-k+1)}} = 2\sqrt{\frac 1{3n^2 -4nk + k^2 + 4n + 1}}$ and as $k \le n$ then $2\sqrt{\frac 1{3n^2 -4nk + k^2 + 4n + 1}}\ge 2\sqrt{\frac 1{4n^2 -4n(k-1) + 1}} \ge \frac 2{2n-1}$ and so the entire sum is   $\ge \frac {2n}{2n-1}$.  That might work but ... we need to work out whether my math actually works.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/534117, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1164493, all found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B2%7D%2B...%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3n%2B1%7D%3E1%24&p=1)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Just observe that $( x \mapsto 1/x )$ is convex so by Jensen's inequality it is trivial. =)

Comment: @fleablood: See my above comment. I don't know why none of the other answers mention this.

Comment: How many ninth graders know what Jensen's inequality is?

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of [Inequality $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{3n+1} \ge 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222943)], later the duplicate target [was changed](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2781862/revisions) to [Mathematical induction for inequalities: $\frac1{n+1} + \frac1{n+2} + \cdots +\frac1{3n+1} > 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1164493). @MichaelRozenberg I am not really sure whether it is ideal to close the question which is *general* as a duplicate of a question that asks *specifically* for induction proof.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was my mistake. I meant the following link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534117

Comment: I'm not at all happy with the evolution here. Originally this was supposed to be done with 9th graders technology. Now one high rep users added their favorite set of tags, another removed the tech restriction from the title, yet others want to close this as a dupe of a question with more answers inaccessible to the OP. Dupe closing is fine (to discourage new answers using high school technology or higher). The rest, not so much IMHO.

Comment: For the record: I only upvoted Achille Hui's answer as that is at the level asked for. I would rather see the other answers compete for upvotes in the dupe target threads.

Comment: For the record (2): I do accept that we provide answers using concepts unfamiliar to the OP. However, in a case like this, with several suitable dupe threads available, I would prefer to stick to the level requirement of the OP. This may be fodder for a detailed meta discussion. I'm largely playing it by ear, and may have overlooked something. No one did anything wrong here, really. Sorry If I gave that impression. It's just that a combination of reasonable actions lead to an IMO unreasonable outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{n+k}\geq\frac{(2n+1)^2}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n+1}(n+k)}=\frac{(2n+1)^2}{\frac{(2(n+1)+2n)(2n+1)}{2}}=1.$$

Comment: Hello Michael, happy to see you here!

Answer (score 9):

There are $2n+1$ terms in the sum, you just need to pair up the terms
symmetrically from both ends, take average and compare with the term in the middle.
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=n+1}^{3n+1} \frac{1}{k} 
&= \sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{1}{2n+1+k}
= \frac12\sum_{k=-n}^n\left(\frac{1}{2n+1+k} + \frac{1}{2n+1-k}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=-n}^n \frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)^2-k^2}
\stackrel{\color{blue}{\text{ assume } n> 0}}{>} \sum_{k=-n}^n \frac{1}{2n+1} = \frac{2n+1}{2n+1} = 1\end{align}$$

Comment: A perfect explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method given in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114321/prove-sum-k-1n-frac1nk-geq-frac712/2114328#2114328) by Jack D'Aurizio.

Note: $H_n=1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n$ is called [$n$-th harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Then:
$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{3n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{n+k}=H_{3n+1}-H_{n}.$$
Consider the sequence: $a_n=H_{3n+1}-H_n$. We will show that it is an increasing sequence:
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=(H_{3(n+1)+1}-H_{n+1})-(H_{3n+1}-H_n)=\\
(H_{3n+4}-H_{3n+1})-(H_{n+1}-H_n)=\\
\frac{1}{3n+4}+\frac{1}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}>\\
\frac{1}{3n+4}+\frac{1}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{3n+\color{red}{3}}+\frac{1}{3n+\color{red}{3}}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\\
\frac{1}{3n+4}>0 \Rightarrow a_{n+1}>a_n.$$
Hence:
$$a_1=H_{3+1}-H_1=\sum_{k=1}^{2+1} \frac{1}{1+k}=\frac12+\frac13+\frac14=\frac {13}{12}>1.$$